# How to support Update, Ivy Resolve, Build

Tags: eclipse, svn, ivy, subversive

"Build automatically" in Eclipse is a handy feature. However, it's painful when I try to do the following workflow:

1. SVN Update using Subversive
2. Ivy Resolve all projects

During the resolve, Eclipse wants to keep building. I've found it's faster if I uncheck Build Automatically and re-check it later. Is there a way I could automate it into a button?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was addressed and fixed in the 2.2.0 version of [IvyDE](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/index.html):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVYDE-177